# Hudson NSIS plugin

Tags: hudson-plugins

I have an asp.net solution. I have installed Ms build plugin to build it. The job is successfully building. Now i want to achieve two things using hudson.
1. Once the build completes, I want to publish the solution.
2. How can I attach existing NSIS script for the creation of windows installer. Is there any specific plugin for NSIS in hudson?
Kindly help me.

Comment: Any success on the Question? Accept answer, if applicable ;) Maybe you can even share your status of using in in your CI server - it would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin:

https://github.com/Elbandi/nsis-plugin

Now trying to use / enable / configure it on my company CI server ...

Answer (score 0):

In your MSBuild file you could have a target that calls Exec to invoke MAKENSIS.EXE

Answer (score -1):

I myself found the solution for this problem.

1. After the Build stage add Execute windows batch command section.
   Here we can add the asp.net web application pulishing command. 
   For instance call:

   ```
   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_compiler.exe" -v /ABC1 -p "F:\TEST" -f -fixednames "%hudson_home%\source" -c
   ```

   Here `F:\TEST` is the target location and `%hudson_home%\source` is the source location.
2. After this we can call our NSIS script using `makensis.exe`, e.g.:

   ```
   makenis.exe tst.nsi
   ```

Done..!!